# How to upload IntelliJ IDEA settings with IDE Setting Sync plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using IDE Setting Sync plugin in IntelliJ IDEA.

In [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/09/intellij-idea-2017-3-eap-better-synchronization-of-your-settings-across-devices-and-other-improvements/) blog, it says I can just click *get settings from account*.

[image]

But how can I upload the settings to the account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Situation #1**: the plugin is enabled on both machines and they're synchronized
A change on any machine will cause update to server's data so you can access in on another machine.

**Situation #2**: you want to fully override the data.
In the case just use `Disable sync` option and choose `Remove settings from cloud`
[image][image]

After that reactive the plugin and your settings will be uploaded to the cloud.